# How check or to load otherView when UITableView is empty?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am try to create the Table test application .
I use table view for that .I need When there is no data in table or when table is empty other view must come instance table view .How can do this.Please give honest answer .
thanks

Comment: are you trying to show like no data or something when there is no data in table cell?

Comment: Please clarify  "must come instance table view".   You could just add an other view over the tableview.

Comment: dear @Kshitiz Ghimire i am trying do  when there is no data in table cell.

Comment: i guess u r populating table from array rite, check if it is empty then return ur custom UITable cell according to your desire, hope i understood your question

Comment: Yes your right But how can do give me sample code hint

Answer (score 0):

In these two delegates check if you have cells in your table. If not present your custom view.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return NumberOfSections;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return NumberOfRows;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong. I think you will be using an array or something to fill the contents of the tableView. So when you load the view you can check if the contents are available for the tableview. If the array is empty then you can show the other view instead of the tableview.

**UPDATE**

This [tutorial](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/08/08/iphone-programming-tutorial-populating-uitableview-with-an-nsarray/) is a nice place to start.

Comment: Yes you are right .I am new this .Can you explain me  with sample code or give link of tutorial for all this to Lerner  .How can i add array value into table and when there is no data in table how can I display other view .Thanks in advance

Comment: But if there is no data  return appDelegate.fruits.count then how can display other view

Comment: Then u add [self.view addSubview:yourOtherView];

Comment: i am do like that is that right - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section { FruitAppDelegate *appDelegate = (FruitAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; return appDelegate.fruits.count; if(appDelegate.fruits.count == nil) { t1 = [[test alloc]initWithNibName:@"test" bundle:nil]; [self.view addSubview:t1]; } }

Comment: You can check this in viewdidLoad itself and then update tableview.

Answer (score 0):

Create custom table cell and when there is no data then return 1 in numberOfRowsInSection and in cellForRowAtIndexPath return custom cell with what ever view you want

good luck

Comment: i am do like that is that right                                    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
 FruitAppDelegate *appDelegate = (FruitAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    return appDelegate.fruits.count;
 if(appDelegate.fruits.count == nil)
 {
  t1 = [[test alloc]initWithNibName:@"test" bundle:nil];
  [self.view addSubview:t1];
 }
}

Comment: try somethin like in url http://kshitizghimire.com.np/insert-customuitableviewcell-in-uitablevew-on-row-selected/ here i have inserted new customcell when one click on table row your need to do is check if your array populating for table cell is empty then return 1 in `- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView ` this method and return your custom cell in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` where custom cell is your new view good luck

Comment: I am  not asking about cell .I am talking about if my table  is empty it means there is no data in the table at that time user see other view it like if i have table of fruits and if there is no fruits data available at that time user see other view where he have to enter some data for table.If is data is enter at that time user see the table view.

Comment: you can use customcell that will cover whole table area and that cell can have ur any uicontrols ,the user in front end see single view which actually is your custom cell taking whole area of table view and at this time table will contain only one cell

Comment: NO I explain you By example :-I have app where country name & details is display in table .If there is no details in on table or (there is no data ).At time user see other view where he can enter the name & details of country .For that i was ask if table is empty he see other view where he have Add country button by click on that he must go on the data entering field once the data is enter and save by the user at this movement now data is available .At this time table view come first .

Comment: ok you can check your data , if nil then don't initialize tableview just presentModalviewcontroller so make new viewcontroller for inserting your data. but you can perform this in customtablecell too as i mention earlier good luck

Comment: i am doing like that is that right wrong if wrong then how can         - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
 FruitAppDelegate *appDelegate = (FruitAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    return appDelegate.fruits.count;
 if(appDelegate.fruits.count == nil)
 {
  t1 =[[test alloc]initWithNibName:@"test" bundle:nil];

  [self presentModalViewController:t1 animated:YES];
  [t1 release];
 }
}

Comment: if(appDelegate.fruits.count == 0) should be this i guess

Comment: how can i  can perform this in customtablecell .But i also have  tabbar on to the table view I dont want tabbar when my other view present .I want my tabbar along with the table only.

Comment: create custom UItableviewcell , your can find help here http://kshitizghimire.com.np/create-custom-uitableviewcell/ , and when your display custom custom cell or when your count is zero just hide tabbar, i think we can hide tabbar. hope this will help